# combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\binom{n}{k}^2 = n\binom{2n-1}{n-1} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Some one can help me to proof this equation please?
I thought about the numbers of ways to choose a group of $n$ from $n$ boys and $n$ girls when the "CEO" must be a boy. But I don't really know how to show it on the left side

Comment: If there are $k$ boys (including the ceo) in the chosen $n$ people, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way to do it.  One the left-hand side, note that $$k\binom{n}{k}^2=k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$$ so we have the number of ways to choose $k$ boys, times the number of ways to choose $n-k$ girls, times the number of ways to choose which boy is "CEO".  Since we must choose at least one boy to be CEO, the sum runs from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: thank you. but is there a way to explain that with words without  writing $k\binom{n}{k}^2=k\binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n-k}$? because i was asked to proof that without any algebraic steps ans i can't understand why we choose k from n twice.

Comment: @tomer Picking $n-k$ girls to be in the group is the same as picking $k$ girls to *not* be in the group.

Comment: ahhh, you are right, i can't belive I didn't see that. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$
Now let $k$ be the number of boys like in your analogy. Now we can choose any number of boys from $1$ to $n$, and then choose $n-k$ girls. Now since a boy must be a "CEO", we have $k$ choices. So the analogies match up perfectly.